# How to fix Apple Mach-O Linker Error Group issue in xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

**I try to implement push notification:**

[Source](https://medium.com/@martco/triggering-ios-actionable-push-notifications-via-react-native-7990a6a3c3f4)

But I Got this issue :

[image]

```
Apple Mach-O Linker Error Group
 no such file or directory: 
 '/Users/arunkumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sample-bskvypzxnjnnszbjeelvenubespf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTPushNotification-tvOS.a
```

How to fix that issue ?

Comment: Close your project and open Xcode -> Window -> Projects -> Locate your project -> Derived data .............. click on Delete option, open your project and build.

Comment: That's Not work @raki

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run **react-native link** this will all for you.
Or use these steps

**Step 1**

**.xcodeproj** file inside it's folder. Drag this file to your project on Xcode (usually under the Libraries group on Xcode)

**Step 2**

Click on your main project file (the one that represents the .xcodeproj) select Build Phases and drag the static library from the Products folder inside the Library you are importing to Link Binary With Libraries

**Step 3**

project's file, select **Build Settings** and search for **Header Search Paths**. There you should include the path to your library (if it has relevant files on subdirectories remember to make it recursive, like React.

refer this one 
[link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios.html)

Comment: Now I'm Linking Libraries @Sport , but now also same error come.

Comment: 1 . First I would  drag <.xcodeproj>  file from ( /node_modules/react-native/Libraries/PushNotificationIOS/ ) to Libraries

Comment: After that I would follow step 2, step 3 instructions . but got same issue .

Comment: Now I got < Check dependencies 
Unable to run command 'Libtool libRCTPushNotification.a' - this target might include its own product.> error @Sport